# Rails: Comparing many record in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4, comparison

I have an article model that has many categories and i want in my article model to compare a given article to others article based on category so if they have the same category i can show to user in the article show page all the article with the same category

I want a help on how can i do that in the article model and not in controller so any one can help me to achieve this?

I'm already doing that in the controller and it is working fine but for some special needs i want it in my model

this is what i'm already doing in my controller

```
Article.includes(:categories)
                    .where('articles.id != ?', @article.id)
                    .where(categories: { id: @article.categories.pluck(:id) } )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

In Article model:

```
scope :scope_name, -> { |article| includes(:categories).where('articles.id != ?', article.id).where(categories: { id: article.categories.pluck(:id) } ) }
```

Now you can use `Article.scope_name` wherever you need.

Comment: And how to use this scope in controller is `Article.scope_name`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance method in your `Article` model like this:

```
def get_category_related_articles _categories
  Article.includes(:categories)
         .where('articles.id != ?', self.id)
         .where(categories: { id: _categories.pluck(:id) } )      
end
```

then, in your controller, you can do:

```
articles = @article.get_category_related_articles(@job.categories)
```

I would put this logic in a model method if I want to reuse this method.
Otherwise, I would use presenters, decorators and concerns in order to keep my controllers clean.

Comment: that is exactly what i was looking for but the problem is that i'm getting this error undefined local variable or method `article'  even if i try def get_category_related_articles(article) then i get wrong number of arguments

Comment: why are you trying to pass article as param? you need to execute the method from the `@article` instance and pass @job.categories. If you loaded @article and @job variables correctly in your controller the `get_category_related_articles` method should work